# Create Custom Data Validation to Reconcile Username on the Backend WorkSheet

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2007

Afternoon guys I am new to excel and I am created an array formula in excel 2007 that will take our employee master list and filter down to the Team Leader level. From there I have created lists. This document however is shared. I ran in to an issue where they can type the user ID in the document and it will match up against there Team Leader and that works fine (when they type it), However some users do not type this in they would rather select there user name from the drop down menu. Well in a shared document they get an error message about Array formulas. I understand this solution will not work. So I came up with an idea to use custom validation and I wanted the user to just type there USERID in and on the back end it will check to see if it exists.... I can't seem to get that to work. Anyone have any ideas for a formula?

Today what I am looking to either find out is how to create a formula that pulls the user name that matches the TL that is not an array formula that works in excel 2007 or figure our what excel formula I could put in to data validation or names list that will allow custom validation to work or the drop downs to work in shared mode without getting the `Array formulas can not be moved around in shared mode.

Here is the current Array formula. This was set up to remove duplicates however is not technically needed. Let me know if any other information that I could add to help other users. Thanks.

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX(Agents1, MATCH(0, IF($P:$P=$W$2, COUNTIF(X$1:X1, Agents1), 1), 0)), "")}
```

I am looking for a custom validation that when you type `CSCHMIDT` in lets say A1 it will look at `Employeelookup$P1:P3999` and will either allow the value to stay or error out in data validation.

Update: Good question. I have created an error tracker for our employees to go out and enter in errors that they encounter. So what they need to do is go out to the excel sheet (each team has there own worksheet) and then they would enter the date that Issue occurred on as well as there USERID. The UserID matches up with the Team leader via Index match. Now seeing that I have teams that will accidentally put information under the wrong tab I had to break down the master list on the back end and filter it with the formula above by team leader so that the User when they select there id will only show up under the tab that they belong to. However in shared because that drop down list is from an array, it gives me an error message. However if the user types there name it works fine. So what I need a custom Data validation that will reference the name they type in and check to see if on the Auto population sheet that has there name listed under that Team leader to be accepted if it matches the back range that there name is within? I can't think of what to put.

Comment: Not sure if I understand but can't you build a hidden sheet and do a `vlookup`? Wrap a conditional `iserror` to catch bad user names.

Comment: I have updated the question above for more details.

Comment: Uh still confused XD Sounds more convoluted than it has to be? I mean, perhaps have separate workbooks for each team?

Comment: You would probably have to see it lol. It would make sense if you were looking at the work book unfortunately I can't share it due to Personal information. Kind of at a loss I guess. No big deal.

Comment: The in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/906311 described workarounds will not suit?